# Failed to start service Sitecore XConnect Search Indexer

Tags: sitecore-install-framework, installation, sitecore-install-assistant

I'm facing this issue when trying to install my first XP 9.2 instance using Sitecore Install Assistant:

[image]

```
[XConnectXP0_StartServices ]:[Updating] jss-sc920xconnect.dev.local-IndexWorker 
Waiting for service 'Sitecore XConnect Search Indexer - jss-sc920xconnect.dev.local-IndexWorker(jss-sc920xconnect.dev.local-IndexWorker)' to start... 
Failed to start service 'Sitecore XConnect Search Indexer - jss-sc920xconnect.dev.local-IndexWorker (jss-sc920xconnect.dev.local-IndexWorker)'. 
[TIME] 00:05:14 Failed to start service 'Sitecore XConnect Search Indexer - jss-sc920xconnect.dev.local-IndexWorker(jss-sc920xconnect.dev.local-IndexWorker)'.
```

Answer (score 3):

So basically my `Sitecore XConnect Search Indexer` can't start.

When looking on its own logs, I found this exception stack trace:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. --->
Sitecore.Nexus.Licensing.LicenseException: Required license is missing: Sitecore.xDB.Base    
    at .(⁫‬‮‍‎⁪⁮‍​⁭⁯⁭‭⁬⁬⁯‎⁪‮⁫‮‪‏⁫‮⁬‏⁭‌‪⁭‎‭‌⁪⁯‍‭‪‬   , String )    
    at Sitecore.XConnect.Configuration.Extensions.InitializeLicenseCheck(IServiceCollection collection, String licenseFile)
    at Sitecore.XConnect.Configuration.Extensions.UseXConnectServiceInitializationConfiguration(IServiceCollection collection, IConfiguration configuration, String configurationSectionName, String initializationSectionName)
    at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer.ServiceProviderFactory.GetDiServiceProvider(IConfiguration config, String modelDirectory)
    at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer.IndexerHostDependencies..ctor(IConfigurationRoot config)
    at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer.IndexerAppDomainHost.IndexerHostAppDomainBridge..ctor()

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---    
    at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
    at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
    at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
    at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
    at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
    at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyString, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
    at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName)
    at System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName)
    at System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(String assemblyName, String typeName)
    at System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(String assemblyName, String typeName)
    at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer.IndexerAppDomainHost.CreateAppDomainAndIndexer()
    at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer.IndexerAppDomainHost.Start()
    at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer.Service.OnStart(String[] args)
```

I can confirm that the license is there. So I decided to open the `license.xml` file to analyze it.

And boom!

`<expiration>20190812T000000</expiration>` which is yesterday.

So if you are facing any issue when trying to start your XConnect services please **make sure you still have a valid license**.